# Save report file to G Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

We run a Google Ads script that sends us a report file in txt format via email each morning. We now want this same file on our Google Drive, created with the same script.

How can we achieve this?

Matt from Google Ads Scripts Team suggested the snippet bellow but i don't know how to use it, i don't have an url for the file.

```
function saveFile() {
  var url = "FILE_URL";
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  DriveApp.createFile(blob);
}
```

Function for sending email is:

```
function SendEmail(recipient, subject, body, message, attachment, mimetype) {
  if (attachment) MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, {attachments:[{fileName: attachment, mimeType: mimetype, content: message}]});
  else MailApp.SendEmail(recipient, subject, message);
}
```

and in function(main) there is this line that sends an email:

```
SendEmail("my_email@domain.com", "Stats Report", report[0], report[2], "report.txt", 'text/plain');
```

Any ideas how to use same variables for saving report.txt to Google Drive?

Comment: what is not working with the code you have?

Comment: If the report file is attached to an email, you can use the `GmailMessage.getAttachments()` method to achieve this quite easily. However, we need more information to be able to understand what the requirement is here.

Comment: The code is working, we get report.txt to our email. We now want the script to also push this file to Google Drive.

Comment: I suggest that you create a folder.Get the attachment. Get the blog and create a file in that folder.

Comment: i know what i have to do, i want to know how :)